# Unhandled exception at 0x6b20d0ac in Ammar_1610852_Assignment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00003232

Tags: c

i'm a beginner,and am getting the below error while trying to write into a text file..seems the issue is while the text file is getting closed.

> Unhandled exception at 0x6b20d0ac in Ammar_1610852_Assignment.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00003232.

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void cust_info();
void bookshop_stack();
void search();
void insert();
void list();
void push();
void display();
void pop();
void main_menu();

void main()
{
    main_menu();
    getch();
}

void main_menu()
{
    int opts;

    //this is welcome message of the app
    printf ("---- Welcome to Ammar's Book Shop----\n\n\n\nPlease Select an Option From Below\n\n 1. Customer Information\n 2. Book Shop Stack \n 3. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&opts);

    //this is the main three options in the app
    switch (opts)
    {
    case 1:
        cust_info();
        break;

    case 2:
        bookshop_stack();
        break;

    case 3:
        printf ("Exit");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
void cust_info()
{
    int sub2_opts;
    printf ("Please Select an Option From Below\n\n 1. Insert \n 2. Search \n 3. List \n 4. Exit \n\n");
    scanf ("%d",&sub2_opts);

    switch (sub2_opts)
    {
    case 1:
        insert();
        break;

    case 2:
        search();
        break;

    case 3:
        list();
        break;

    case 4:
        main_menu();
        break;

    default:
        printf ("Please select a valid option\n");
        break;
    }
}
void bookshop_stack()
{
        int bs_opts;
    printf ("Please Select an Option From Below\n\n 1. Push \n 2. Search \n 3. Display \n 4. Exit \n\n");
    scanf ("%d",&bs_opts);

    switch (bs_opts)
    {
    case 1:
        push();
        break;

    case 2:
        display();
        break;

    case 3:
        pop();
        break;

    case 4:
        main_menu();
        break;

    default:
        printf ("Please select a valid option\n");
        break;
    }
}
void search()
{
printf ("hello this is search screen");
}
void list()
{
    char buf[256];
    std::ifstream inFile("bookshop_DB.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }
    while (inFile >> buf) {
        std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    }

    inFile.close();

}
void push()
{

}
void display()
{

}
void pop()
{

}
void insert()
{
    int phon,bsn,dob,id,dop,dor,fa,opsn;
    char name[30],adds[30],bt[50],ban[50];
    FILE * bookdetails;
    bookdetails = fopen ("bookshop_DB.txt","a");

    printf ("Enter Customer Name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf ("Enter Customer ID\n");
    scanf ("%d",& id);
    printf ("Enter Customer Address\n");
    scanf ("%s",adds);
    printf ("Enter Customer Phone Number\n");
    scanf ("%d",&phon);
    printf ("Enter Book Serial Number\n");
    scanf ("%s",&bsn);
    printf ("Enter Book Title\n");
    scanf ("%s",bt);
    printf ("Enter Book Author Name\n");
    scanf ("%s",ban);
    printf ("Enter Date of Borrow\n");
    scanf ("%s",&dob);
    printf ("Enter Date of Publish\n");
    scanf ("%s",&dop);
    printf ("Enter Date of Return\n");
    scanf ("%s",&dor);
    printf ("Enter Fine Amount\n");
    scanf ("%s",&fa);

    fprintf (bookdetails,"%s %d %s %d %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", name,id,adds,phon,bsn,bt,ban,dob,dop,dor,fa);
    fclose (bookdetails);

    printf ("Deatils have been saved successfully..!!\n\n Press 1 to Main Menu or 0 to Exit\n");
    scanf ("%d",&opsn);
    switch (opsn)
    {
        case 1:
            cust_info();
            break;

        case 0:
            break;
            default:

        printf ("Please select a valid option\n");
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: actually am a student and new to C, and am not able to figure it our even after using a debugger

Comment: The code shown won't compile in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the wrong format specifier for both `scanf` and `fprintf`.

One example:

```
printf ("Enter Fine Amount\n");
scanf ("%s",&fa);
```

The variable `fa` is an integer but you try to scan using `%s`. The same goes for `fprintf` where you try to print an integer using `%s`. Use `%s` for strings. For an integer use `%d`.

The variable `fa` is just one example. There are more... (e.g. `dor`) -  so check all your format specifiers.

**BTW** Don't call `main_menu` when you want to get back to it. Just use a return. So instead of:

```
case 4:
    main_menu();
    break;
```

Simply do:

```
case 4:
    return;
```

Comment: sure, this is what i did by now.